# Find the power series representation for arctan.

Tags: calculus

Find a power series representation for the following function and determine the interval of convergence:

$f(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)$

So I found its derivative and used U-subsitution and came up with

$\frac{1}{(1+(9/4x^2)}$

which looks like

$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n $

Now I am trying to figure out what to do next. 

Somebody told me that I need to take the integral of $\frac{1}{(1+(3/2x)^2)}$, that does not make any sense at all though because that basically puts it back to $\arctan(3x/2)$.

what do you guys think?

Comment: if someone has answered your question sufficiently please indicate so by accepting an answer, this removes it from the top of the "active" list. If it has not been answered sufficiently, ask questions in comments to try to get there or close it if you are no longer interested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at your derivative again to make sure it is right (it is not quite, but close). You are on the right track, you have the form $\frac{1}{1+y}$, you want $\frac{1}{1-y}$, what do you have to do to your $y$ term to get this? When someone told you to integrate, they mean integrate the power series. You know you can do this in the interval of convergence, right? You are right, once you integrate it you will get $\arctan$ again, but you will also have the integral of the power series on one side which is then the power series for $\arctan$!

Comment: I could write it as 1/(1-(-9/4x)^2)? When you say, integrate the power series, does that mean integrate 1/(1-(-9/4x)^2)? or do the power series of 1/(1-(-9/4x)^2) and then integrate that result?? When I do integral of 1/(1-(-9/4x)^2), I get....4/9 tanh^(-1)((9 x)/4)

Comment: I don't know if those questions I asked above make sense or not..Just let me know!

Comment: Take a look at Mhenni's answer. If you take the derivative of $\arctan$ you get what he has as his integrand. You can then represent that as a power series and integrate the power series term by term, or you can integrate the generating term of your power series.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start.

$$ \tan^{-1}(3x/2) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{3/2}{1+9t^2/4} dt.$$

Now, use the power series of the integrand and integrate term by term.